# Cannot Read Property _id of undefined. Angular Image Upload Service Type Error

Tags: angular, typescript, express, mongoose, angular-services

I am trying to upload and display images in my angular component. For the backend I am using Mongoose, Express, MongoDB and Multer for the image uploads. I have tested my backend and it works fine. In my Angular component, when I try to upload the image, it successfully gets uploaded to my server and saved to the database. However, it does not display in my component and when I click the "Add Image" button, it throws an error of "Cannot Read Property _id of undefined" in my image Service.
This is the code for my Image Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Gallery } from '../post/gallery';
import { Subject } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ImageService {
  private images: Gallery[] = [];
  private images$ = new Subject<Gallery[]>();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  addImages(name: string, image: File): void {
    const imageData = new FormData();
    imageData.append("name", name);
    imageData.append("image", image, name);
    this.http.post<{ gallery: Gallery }>('http://localhost:3000/gallery/archive', imageData)
      .subscribe((imageData) => {
        const gallery: Gallery = {
          _id: imageData.gallery._id, //WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
          name: name,
          avatar: imageData.gallery.avatar,
        };
        this.images.push(gallery);
        this.images$.next(this.images);
      });
  }
```

Everything else runs smoothly. The image gets uploaded to the server and saved to the db when I click Add Image, but this error occurs. Can someone Please Explain what's causing this error and How can I resolve it? Any help is greatly appreciated Thank You very Much.

Comment: **1.** Is the `const gallery` variable initialized correctly despite the error? **2.** If not, are you sure the `gallery` property is defined in the `imageDate` variable? Do a `console.log(imageData)` inside the subscription and check if the property `gallery` is defined in it.

Comment: When I console.log the imageData, it gives me _id, name, avatar and uploaded values correctly.

Comment: "Is the `const gallery` variable initialized correctly despite the error"??

Comment: How do I check if it's initialized correctly?

Comment: The subscription to `this.images$` observable would receive the array with the new `gallery` pushed to it.

Comment: It's initialized properly.

Comment: Then it's a plain linter error. You either have to define the type in the subscription callback: `.subscribe((imageData: Gallery) => {...`. Or use bracket notation instead of dot notation: `imageData['gallery'].['_id']` and `imageData['gallery']['avatar']`.

Comment: It worked perfectly. THANK YOU. Just out of curiosity, what would happen if the gallery object was not initialized properly? And how would one go about to solve that?

Comment: In that case, like mentioned before the first step would be to check if the property is available in the response from the server.

Comment: And if it's not?

Comment: You check the back-end to verify if it returns the object as expected.

Comment: Another problem occurred. Now when I click the Add Image button it does not display the image in the component. When I console.logged the this.images(gallery), it returns me `{id: undefined, name: null, avatar: undefined}`. What's causing this problem now?

Comment: I suggest opening a new question with the relevant details.